# How to troubleshoot infinite Windows 7 boot loop

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 7 Home edition. In trying to install Windows 7 Ultimate, at installation screen, I deleted all the partitions including the recovery partition and installed Ultimate. Now, the problem with my Samsung Series 7 Chronos laptop is it will enter an infinite boot loop, not allowing me to log in to Windows unless I have a bootable USB or CD inserted into the laptop at start up. I tried doing a system repair with the install disk, but Windows didn't find a problem. Any ideas how I could troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Have you tried safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

We have an infinite-loop boot problem at my place of work that may or may not be relevant to your specific problem. Worth at least testing.

If you're able to enter BIOS, test different "SATA Controller Mode" settings. If it defaults to AHCI, try Compatibility (and visa versa). This solves our issue, as we immediately image the stock SSD to have a Windows XP partition that conflicts with the stock Windows 7 partition for some reason.